# How to offset the keyframes on an action with Python

Tags: python, animation

I want to offset the keyframes on a specific action. I found this script which does something similar to what I want, but it offsets the keyframes on every action in the scene:

```
arm_action = bpy.data.actions

for action in arm_action:
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            point.co.x -= 50
```

I'm trying to directly refer to the action that I want to offset with the line:

```
arm_action = bpy.context.scene.objects['Armature'].animation_data.action
```

But I got the following error: *'Action' object is not iterable*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import bpy

arm_action = bpy.data.actions['ArmatureAction']



for fcurve in arm_action.fcurves:
    for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
        point.co.x += 10
```

Comment: hey sorry bro we answered at the same time but i noticed you got it first XD

Comment: no problem, that's life ;) no need to say sorry. And i have enough reputation...it's good if the "young ones" got some points ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse. That is because `bpy.context.scene.objects['Armature'].animation_data.action` is not a list of objects. You can also see that the ending is `.action` and is singular not plural. It's only a single object and you can't iterate on a single object.

Just omit the first `for` loop:

```
arm_action = bpy.context.scene.objects['Armature'].animation_data.action
action = arm_action

for fcurve in action.fcurves:
    for point in fcurve.keyframe_points:
        point.co.x -= 50
```